# Will trial version of Visual Studio professional 2012 works fine?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows, trial

I am going to develop a windows application for a customer which takes probably one month for development. As our company doesnot want to invest much for this project can i use trial version of Visual Studio professional 2012? will it cover all features and will be ok for deployment? 
i see it is easy to extend with paied version in case the project will be extended

Comment: you haven't rights to deploy products made with Trial Version.

Comment: Question involves EULA, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per EULA: You may only use the trial software for internal evaluation purposes.

That would mean that it should not be used to deploy the software compiled with it.

Answer (score 1):

The trial version works for 90 days so that should work. But then if they want maintenance done on the application they will have to install the Visual Studio 2012 Trial again, on another PC (or re-install Windows first on the original PC, and then re-install Visual Studio 2012 trial on it), or purchase a full license.

Do you need all the features of Visual Studio 2012? Perhaps the [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) (which is free) is capable enough. Then there will be no problem with an expired license etc.

Comment: I did not get ur answer. In case we need to do maintenance on the application cannot we just buy the lisence and continue work on it?

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I guess in this case we are fine with that since the project is small and maybe the customer wants to continue do the maintenace not us. And they alreayd have a peid version of VS

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can download the express version of VS using this address http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-8.

Of course there are some differences between the paid version and this one, but basically both are the same software.

I think the biggest difference is the fact that the professional edition wraps all the supported environments and the express edition you have to download whatever you want separately.